# Make a label appear on a subview

Tags: cocoa-touch, uilabel, subview

Hi I am creating an app where you have to pop pimples. Right now I have it so that everytime you pop a pimple, a UILabel called popcount text is +1. I have another label that I have set hidden called the score which I stated should have the same text as popcount text. You have 10 seconds to pop as many pimples as you can . Once the timer reaches 0 a gameover subview is added. I have said that the score.hidden = NO; 
But when I say this the label does not appear on the subview. It is probably behind it. How can I fix this so it can be on the subview.

I am using Xcode

Comment: Please post the relevant code.

Answer (score 2):

When you said score.hidden = NO;  add this line below [self.view bringSubviewToFront:score];